# Set nested model attribute with a variable as a key

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using DeepModel to access nested attributes in a Backbone.js model. So this works fine:

```
this.model.set({'chart_configs.mentions_bar_graph.date': "cats"});
```

However, I'd like to use a variable as part of my key so like:

```
this.model.set({'chart_configs.'+ this.chartName + '.date': "cats"});
```

Is this some how possible? I know that I can do it by

```
this.model.attributes.chart_configs["mentions_bar_graph"].date = "cats";
```

But that, obviously, does not trigger a "change" event else where in my code.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Model#set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) can be called in two ways:

```
m.set('key', 'value');
m.set(an_object_of_keys_and_values);
```

So you should be able to get past the "you can't define an object literal like that" problem by using the first form of `Model#set`:

```
this.model.set('chart_configs.' + this.chartName + '.date', 'cats');
```

If DeepModel doesn't like that then you could do it the long way:

```
var values = { };
values['chart_configs.' + this.chartName + '.date'] = 'cats';
this.model.set(values);
```

An object is an object whether it has a name or not and `set` only cares about the keys and values.

Comment: here is the code working for the mu is too short explanation. http://jsfiddle.net/9cvVv/490/

Comment: Looks like deepmodel allows me to use your first solution. Thanks for explaining!